# check whether the function needs parameters

Tags: php

for example I need some code like:

```
if(need_params('function_name')):
    print 'function_name($params)';
else
    print 'function_name()';
endif;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have a look into the [ReflectionFunction Class](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php).

```
<?php
function need_params($func) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($func);

    return $reflection->getNumberOfParameters();
}

// use
function foo($arg) {}

echo need_params('foo') > 0 ? 'Needs params' : 'No params';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of function arguments through [`getNumberOfParamers()`](http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php).

You can check whetther the result is `> 0`.

Comment: How about optional arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to do this:

```
function need_params($func_name)
{
    $reflect = new ReflectionFunction($func_name);

    return !empty($reflect->getParameters());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find that out using the [**Reflection API**](http://www.php.net/reflection).

The [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getNumberOfParameters()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php) method looks like exactly what you need, in order to know whether a function expects some parameters.

And you can take a look at the [**`ReflectionFunction`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) for a list of what you can do with it.